# R how to create table from dataframe containing counts over groups?

Tags: r, dataframe, count, tabulate

I have a dataframe with the count of for instance males and females for certain groups arranged in this way:

```
df <- data.frame (
  Round = c("R1", "R1", "R2", "R2"),
  N. = c(20, 10, 15,15),
  Gender = c("M", "F", "M","F"))
```

How can I create a table accounting for counts over, for instance, Round and Gender? I would like to show the distribution of gender for each round.

I have tried

```
table (df$Gender, df$Round)
```

but this is not what I need. I need instead to show N. by groups.

Comment: Unclear what the expected output is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```r
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(df, names_from = Round, values_from = N.)

  Gender    R1    R2
1 M         20    15
2 F         10    15
```

Or in base R with `reshape`:

```r
reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar = "Gender", timevar = "Round")
```

Comment: yes, exactly like that thanks